# Body Overflowing on background

Tags: html, css, image, background, overflow

For my homepage I have a background set as `width: 80%;` and then aligned to center.

**Homepage:**
[image: homepage]

For this I have used the following code:

```
<body id="top"style="height:100%;overflow-x:hidden;background:red;" bgcolor="#FF0000">
```

Now when I zoom the size of the browser it goes like this:

[image: image 2]

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: We cannot often diagnose from an image. Please provide your CSS & HTML. Ideally a JSFiddle or at worst a live link would also assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using percents it will always adjust to your screen, so when you have a screen of 1024 px width it will be 80% of that, but if you resize it to 700px, it will be 80% of that.

Did you use percents on other elements? It's not a bad habit to use them, only you should use them in an element with a fixed width to prevent stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
 width:80%;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: no it is not working plz.. give me another suggestion or if u have similar code the plz. share wid me

Answer (score 0):

Define just your `body`  `min-width`

```
body{
min-width:1000px; // width of you main container 
}
```